# How search through a dictionary?

Tags: swift

Created some quiz questions set, each question has a quiz category. How do I search through the dictionary to print questions that have the same quiz category selected by user.

Sorry still new to dictionary, still trying to wrap the concept around my head.

```
import UIKit

var list = [(categoryText: "Numbers", imageText: "Ten", audioText: "Ten"), (categoryText: "Numbers", imageText: "Eight", audioText: "Eight"), (categoryText: "Numbers", imageText: "Five", audioText: "Five"), (categoryText: "Colors", imageText: "Yellow", audioText: "Yellow"), (categoryText: "Colors", imageText: "Blue", audioText: "Blue"), (categoryText: "Colors", imageText: "Red", audioText: "Red") ]

let selectedCategory = "Numbers"

let q = list.filter { (($0 = "Numbers")) }

print(q)
```

Able to print the quiz base on array index nut would like to be able to select questions that have the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import UIKit
var list = [(categoryText: "Numbers", imageText: "Ten", audioText: "Ten"), (categoryText: "Numbers", imageText: "Eight", audioText: "Eight"), (categoryText: "Numbers", imageText: "Five", audioText: "Five"), (categoryText: "Colors", imageText: "Yellow", audioText: "Yellow"), (categoryText: "Colors", imageText: "Blue", audioText: "Blue"), (categoryText: "Colors", imageText: "Red", audioText: "Red") ]

let selectedCategory = "Numbers"
var selectedCatagoryArray = [Any]()

for index in list {
    if index.categoryText == selectedCategory {
        selectedCatagoryArray.append(index)
    }
}

print(selectedCatagoryArray.description)
```

if you do a better coding structure , I would suggest

```
struct Question {
    var categoryText : String?
    var imageText : String?
    var audioText : String?
}

var list = [Question(categoryText: "Numbers", imageText: "Ten", audioText: "Ten"), Question(categoryText: "Numbers", imageText: "Eight", audioText: "Eight"), Question(categoryText: "Numbers", imageText: "Five", audioText: "Five"), Question(categoryText: "Colors", imageText: "Yellow", audioText: "Yellow"), Question(categoryText: "Colors", imageText: "Blue", audioText: "Blue"), Question(categoryText: "Colors", imageText: "Red", audioText: "Red") ]

let selectedCategory = "Numbers"
var selectedCatagoryArray = [Question]()

for question in list {
    if question.categoryText == selectedCategory {
        selectedCatagoryArray.append(question)
    }
}

for element in selectedCatagoryArray {
    print("Question : \(element.categoryText) + with image Text : \(element.imageText) + with audioText : \(element.audioText)" )
}
```

Comment: Why do you suggest optional members in the struct? All values are clearly non-optional (the code compiles even without question marks). And why `var`iables? The values are clearly supposed to be constants (`let`).